# What does the option "Fast ABI" do?

Tags: c++-winrt

I can't find any documentation on this option.
What does it do? Are there disadvantages to it or why is it not used by default?[image: VS Property Pages]

**Edit:**

According to this CppWinRT NuGet package [readme](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/896d31f/nuget/readme.md) the C++/WinRT compilers default value for the CppWinRTFastAbi option is `false`. I extrapolated that this would be used in my project as well since it doesn't seem to be inheriting a value here.

Comment: There is very little information publicly available on the *"Fast ABI"* feature. There's a short mention of it in Kenny Kerr's and Scott Jones' Build 2019 talk titled [Meet C++/WinRT 2.0](https://youtu.be/X41j_gzSwOY?t=2557). Ultimately, what it accomplishes is getting rid of many (or all) `QueryInterface` calls. My guess is that this is implemented by composing interface hierarchies into a single v-table. Again, little information on this. The only hints I found are in the same speakers' CppCon 2017 talk [C++/WinRT and the Future of C++ on Windows](https://youtu.be/7TdpWB_vRZM?t=3310).

Comment: Using *"Fast ABI"* is a breaking change, which might explain, why it is off by default. If it is indeed off at all. The UI shows the value as *"not set"*, which means that it gets inherited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastabi is a feature primarily geared toward larger APIs that are heavily versioned and/or hierarchical. If your API is not versioned or hierarchical then it probably won't add much value. It is however backward compatible so you can turn it on later on when you decide you need it.